# Set default value of an enum (Java)

Tags: java, function, inheritance, methods, enums

I am writing some inheritance code that displays the information of a worker in a company. There are three statuses the worker can have which are placed in an enum. {TEMPORARY,PART_TIME, FULL_TIME}. The default status is TEMPORARY. The problem that I am having in my code when I run it is that when I do not mention the status of the worker it is supposed to print out "TEMPORARY" but it prints out "null" instead and I am unsure on how to fix it. What I assume about this problem is that I believe an enum is similar to an array and I should give it some kind of value then change it later.

This is my code:

```
class Faculty extends Employee{

        private Status status;

    public Faculty(){
            status = Status.TEMPORARY;
    }

    public Faculty(String name, String email, String phoneNumber){
        super(name, email, phoneNumber);
    }

    public Faculty(String name, String email, String phoneNumber, String office, double salary, Status status){
        super(name, email, phoneNumber, office, salary);
        this.status = status;
    }

    public void setStatus(Status status){
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getStatus(){
        return " Status: " + status;
    }

    @Override
   public String toString(){
      return getName() + getEmail() + getPhoneNumber() + getOffice() + " Salary: " + getSalary() + getStatus();
   }
}
```

Comment: An enum (like your "Status") *CAN HAVE NO "DEFAULT" VALUE*.  Any more than an int can have a "default number", or a string can have a "default character".  It's the *employee* who can have a *default status*.  PROBLEM: You only set the default in one constructor, not all of them.  POSSIBLE SOLUTION: change your member declaration to `private Status status = Status.TEMPORARY;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your are using the second constructor to create your `Faculty`.  However, this constructor never sets the `status` field to anything, but leaves it null.

To make sure that the `status` has a value, you have to add a line to the constructor:

```java
public Faculty(String name, String email, String phoneNumber){
  super(name, email, phoneNumber);
  this.status = Status.TEMPORARY;
}
```

Or you could add the initialization to the field declaration: `private Status status = Status.TEMPORARY;`

Some other comments about the code:

- It is still possible to set `status` to `null` in the third constrcutor or via the setter. You probably want throw an exception/use a default value in this case.
- Setters and Getters should have the same datatype. `getStatus` should return the status, not a formatted string version of it.

Answer (score 2):

If you give the `status` field a value directly when defining it in the `Faculty` class, then that will be the value given to the field by default.

```java
private Status status = Status.TEMPORARY;
```

This means that you no longer have to set it manually in the constructors that do not change the field from its default value of `TEMPORARY`.

```java
public Faculty(){
   // status = Status.TEMPORARY; This line can be removed.
}
```

Something to also note is that when you call the `super` constructor from this constructor in the `Faculty` class:

```java
public Faculty(String name, String email, String phoneNumber){
    super(name, email, phoneNumber);
}
```

the default `Faculty` constructor you wrote (the one that sets `status` to `TEMPORARY`) is not called, so that might be why the `status` field still was null even though you give it a default value in the default constructor. Setting the default value directly in the field solves this issue, but it's still useful to keep this in mind!